# JavaScript | Array Duplicate

Tags: javascript

What do I need to modify, so the user can not enter a duplicate number from the array?

```js
let array = [];

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    let userInput = prompt('Enter a number');
    if(userInput !== array){
        array.push(userInput);
    }else if(userInput == array){
        alert('the element is same');
    }
    
}
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to this:

```
    let array = [];
    
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        let userInput = prompt('Enter a number');
        if(!array.includes(userInput)){
            array.push(userInput);
        }else {
            i--
            alert('the element is same');
        }
    if (i === 3) console.log(array);
    }
```